# Accessing the items of other List through Event receiver of a List

Tags: development, event-receivers, visual-studio-2013, sharepoint-server

I have two lists "**List A**" and "**List B**"

List B has columns:

**Color** [Single line of text]
**Description** [Multiple lines of text]

and now how can I get the "**Color**" and "**Description**" of the second Item present in the "**List B**" by triggering an Event Receiver in **List A** ??

Can anyone please help me ??

P.s : All Items that are present in the **List B**have unique Colors and Description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample code for your reference.

```
public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {


                using (SPWeb oWeb = properties.OpenWeb())
                {

                    SPList oList = oWeb.Lists.TryGetList("listB");
                    SPListItem item = oList.GetItemById(2);
                    object color = item["Color"];
                    object des = item["Des"];
                }


            base.ItemAdding(properties);
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Again thanks a lot